# What is the simplest and safest method to generate an API KEY and SECRET in Python

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I need to generate an API key and secret that would be stored in a Redis server. What would be the best way to generate a key and secret?

I am developing a Django-tastypie framework-based app.

Comment: There's `get_random_string` in `django.utils.crypto`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25943850/django-package-to-generate-random-alphanumeric-string

Answer (score 75, accepted):

For **python3.6+**

```
import secrets

generated_key = secrets.token_urlsafe(length)
```

For **older versions of python**:

for a very secure way of generating random number, you should use urandom:

```
from binascii import hexlify

key = hexlify(os.urandom(length))
```

this will produce bytes, call `key.decode()` if you need a string

For **general non-secure random strings**, with more settings, you can just generate keys of your desired length the python way:

```
import random
import string

def generate_key(length):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(length))
```

And then you can just call it with your desired length `key = generate_key(40)`.
You can specify what alphabet you want to use, for example using only `string.ascii_lowercase` for key consisting of only lowercase letters etc.

There is also Model for Api authentication in tastypie, might be worth checking out https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication.html#apikeyauthentication

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, os.urandom() is both easy and the safest.

Comment: Scroll down if you're using Python 3.6+. There is much simpler solution proposed by Moby Duck.

Answer (score 102):

If you're on Python 3.6 or later, the [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) module is the way to go:

> The secrets module is used for generating cryptographically strong random numbers suitable for managing data such as passwords, account authentication, security tokens, and related secrets.
>
> In particular, secrets should be used in preference to the default pseudo-random number generator in the random module, which is designed for modelling and simulation, not security or cryptography.

e.g. to generate a 16 byte token:

```
>>> import secrets
>>> secrets.token_urlsafe(16)
'zs9XYCbTPKvux46UJckflw'
>>> secrets.token_hex(16)
'6bef18936ac12a9096e9fe7a8fe1f777'
```

Comment: Thanks! Here's a version to invoke straight from the terminal:
`python -c 'import secrets; print(secrets.token_urlsafe(16))'`

Comment: For Windows users running Pawel's code via cmd, if you get the error `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`, replace the single quotes with double quotes

Comment: Any inputs on the differences between `token_urlsafe` and `token_hex`? For which use case each one of those is recommended?

Comment: It would probably be best to save in the database only a *hash* of a generated token, if it's not too far off topic, would you please recommend method(s) for computing a hash also?

Comment: It says, "designed for modelling and simulation, not security or cryptography". Will it be safe to use in prod?

Comment: @RahulDey It says *should be used in preference to the default pseudo-random number generator in the random module, which is designed for...* so this info is not about `secrets` but about `random`.

Answer (score 4):

you can also use following module to generate random string

```
 1 - os.urandom(64).encode('hex') #from os module
 2 - uuid.uuid4()                 # from uuid module
 3 - get_random_string(length=32) #from django.utils.crypto
 4 - secrets.token_hex(64)         #from secrets >= python 3.6
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding answer as I can't comment on T. Opletals answer.

You should not use random.choice as random isn't cryptographically secure. A better option would be random.SystemRandom() which uses the system source of randomness, on linux this would be urandom.

```
def generate_key(length):
    char_set = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation                    
    urand = random.SystemRandom()                                           
    return ''.join([urand.choice(char_set) for _ in range(length)])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an easy-to-use but highly customisable key generator, use `key-generator` pypi package.

> [Here](https://github.com/Sahith02/key-generator) is the GitHub repo where you can find the complete documentation.

Here's an example:

```
from key_generator.key_generator import generate

custom_key = generate(2, ['-', ':'], 3, 10, type_of_value = 'char', capital = 'mix', seed = 17).get_key()
print(custom_key)  # ZLFdHXIUe-ekwJCu
```

Hope this helps :)

Disclaimer: This uses the `key-generator` library which I made.